# Python Dictionary: Iterating values in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to iterate values inside a list but I get this kind of output which is I don't like:

First I have a dictionary, and I converted it into lists.

```
listb=[{'id': '1b33b33f-8e92-4068-a459-0a1de0febb7c'}, {'id': 'c56502b9-0632-4f9f-88b9-70f40e61ef5d'}]
```

Code for converting dictionary values into a list:

```
vol = [i["id"] for i in listb]
```

and I wanted to iterate the values inside a lists:

```
for i in vol:
    print(i[0])
```

But I get these values:

```
1
c
```

The desired output would be:

```
1b33b33f-8e92-4068-a459-0a1de0febb7c
c56502b9-0632-4f9f-88b9-70f40e61ef5d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is the complete id.

`i[0]` is the 0th index, or the first character in the `string i`.

In this case,

```
1b33b33f-8e92-4068-a459-0a1de0febb7c[0] = 1
c56502b9-0632-4f9f-88b9-70f40e61ef5d[0] = c
```

Simply print the entire element, rather than just the index.

Change your code to:

```
for i in vol:
    print(i)
```

I would even suggest you rename your variable `i` to `id`.

```
for id in vol:
    print(id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change your print statement to like this:

```py
for i in vol:
    print(i)
```

### Explanation:

When you run this:

```py
vol = [i["id"] for i in listb]
```

The contents in vol look like this:

```py
>>> vol
['1b33b33f-8e92-4068-a459-0a1de0febb7c', 'c56502b9-0632-4f9f-88b9-70f40e61ef5d']
```

So you just need to print every element in the list `vol`. When you write `i[0]` what happens is that you are accessing the first element of the string in `i`.